# unknown error: Cannot create default profile directory (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python selenium with some arguments and facing this error in Ubuntu Linux. I am new to python and Linux and am not really sure how to debug this error. The code is as below:

```
username = os.getenv("HOME")
userProfile = username + "/" + ".config/google-chrome/default"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format(userProfile))
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",
                                    ["ignore-certificate-errors", "safebrowsing-disable-download- 
                                      protection",
                                     "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update",
                                     "disable-client-side-phishing-detection"])

chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebdriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot create default profile directory

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `username + "/" + ".config/google-chrome/default"`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I didn't get ur ques... I am adding that line to refer to a default directory. This code works well in windows but is giving an error in Linux. I checked the path of the chromedriver too and its correct. I found the default value of userProfile through internet and that's what I have entered.